# OpenCV: ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity while cropping an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have batchs of 2000 images that needs to be cropped. I am trying to do this using opencv.

All the images are of the same format.

Sample Image:

[image]

I am cropping it to:

[image]

It works fine for most of the images, but for some it doesn't.

I keep getting an error:

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

Here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v6ds2h14rsagi1p/AAC2f_qWWQ1nNqoftuuRUD_Fa?dl=0) to the images for which I keep getting the above error.

Here's my code.

```
import numpy as np
import os, shutil
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv
from pprint import pprint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def utilCropImage( img, dictPointValues = None ):

    if dictPointValues != None:
        x = dictPointValues[ 'x' ]
        y = dictPointValues[ 'y' ]
        w = dictPointValues[ 'w' ]
        h = dictPointValues[ 'h' ]

    crop_img = img[y:y+h, x+55:x+w ]
    cv.waitKey(0)

    return crop_img

def cropImage( imageToBeCropped ):

    img = cv.imread( imageToBeCropped )

    if img is None:
        print( "Error reading the image" )
        sys.exit(0)

    gray = cv.cvtColor( img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY )
    __, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours( gray, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )

    counter = 0
    for contour in contours:
        counter += 1
        x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect( contour )
        roi = img[ y: y+h , x: x+w ]

    return ( utilCropImage( img, { 'x': x, 'y': y, 'w': w, 'h': h } ) )



DIR_PATH = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx/'
OUTPUT_PATH = 'yyyyyy/'

lst = os.listdir(  DIR_PATH )
for i in lst:
    image = DIR_PATH + i
    cv.imwrite( OUTPUT_PATH + i , cropImage( image ))
    cv.waitKey(0)
```

Can someone guide me, where exactly am I going wrong. I'm new to opencv.

Thanks.

Comment: "where exactly am I going wrong" -- First of all, you didn't include a proper [mcve] (we shouldn't have to add imports and fix the messed up indentation to make it run...). Second, you didn't add an input image that reproduces the error. Third, you ignored and didn't post the stack trace that accompanies the error message, which identifies **where** the error originated from. Please fix that, and try to do some debugging -- e.g. inspecting the values of variables used in that statement.

Comment: Now, if I were to make a wild guess, I'd say the culprit is `crop_img = img[y:y+h, x+55:x+w ]` in situation when `w <= 55`.

Comment: @DanMašek, you're right. The images which are failing have w < 55. But ideally it should be above 55, as the format of all the images are same and it works fine for 80% of the images. Can you please explain, why is it not working for other images. I have attached a link for the images which are failing, you can have a look at it.